# Issue with SP in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I have asp.net mvc 4 project where try to call T-SQL where I need to select some rows with not all columns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_name]
@iSkip int, @iTake int
    AS
    BEGIN 
    SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] FROM [dbo].[Table] WITH(NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY 
     [Column1] DESC
OFFSET  @iSkip ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @iTake ROWS ONLY 
    END
```

But when I try to call this SP from code I have the following error

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Model.Table'. A member of the type, 'Column4', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

When I try to call this on MS SQL Studio everything is ok, does anybody know where is my mistake? And what I should to do?

Edit:

This is in the Repository:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllEntitiesWithParam(string procedureName, int param1, int param2) {
            return _context.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("EXEC " + procedureName + " @param1, @param2", new SqlParameter("param1", param1), new SqlParameter("param2", param2));
        }
```

And here is inside code:

```
IEnumerable<Table> list = _myRepo.GetAllEntitiesWithParam("SP_name", par1, par2);
```

Comment: You are going to need to show the code you use to call the stored procedure.

Comment: It says `Column4` not present. Update your query and add `[Column4]` in the selection and check,

Comment: @Bharadwaj I understand the error, I dont know what I should to do.

Comment: @BorHunter `SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3],[Column4] FROM [dbo].[Table]` (select `Column4` also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear - you have a `Column4` in your model that is not in the result set of the sproc.  You could add a "default" value to the sproc result:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_name]
@iSkip int, @iTake int
    AS
    BEGIN 
    SELECT [Column1], 
           [Column2], 
           [Column3],
           NULL AS [Column4]     // <----------------
    FROM [dbo].[Table] WITH(NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY 
     [Column1] DESC
OFFSET  @iSkip ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @iTake ROWS ONLY 
    END
```

Comment: Is this the same if I call this column as SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4] ?

Comment: @BorHunter No. In that case you would get whatever values are in `Column4`.

Comment: I mean from the productivity side, not from the data side.

Comment: Not sure I follow, but `Column4` will be a column in the set returned from the sproc, so yes, you could pull it using a `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, It's very interesting.